# LiveCD iso boot into VMWare Kernel Panic

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel-panic

I'm trying to boot theiso for hacking: the art of exploitation into VMWare Workstation and for whatever reason it's not working. I know other people have had this problem as there's a [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782063/cannot-boot-because-kernel-panic-not-syncingfatal-exception-interrupt) and [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/hacking/comments/6tkkrv/hacking_the_art_of_exploitation_2nd_edition/) regarding it. However, the stack overflow post didn't seem to fix my problem and all the links from the reddit post are dead. Here is a picture of the error. Thanks for the help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After trawling the internet for quite a long time, I found a follow-up reddit post that provided the neccesary clarity. I hope this helps you all too!

https://www.reddit.com/r/hacking/comments/9sfkab/hacking_the_art_of_exploitation_2nd_edition/